# Fail to return a string from in a function from another function

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript1.8, typescript1.5

I have this 3 functions that triggers POST api calls, and I want to return a succsess/failure message to whoever calls it (`Observable<string>`).

So the messages are similar and I didnt wan to repeat myself then I added a new function to get success message. But from some reason it dosent work, I see a blank page when I run the app, but if instead of calling `getSuccessMessage` I just pass a regular string ("Something") it works...

weird, those are my funcs:

```
export enum ListType {Cars, Animals, Books}

 public updateOne(carList: Car[]): Observable<string> {
    return this._myApiSevice.postCarsNewOrder(carList)
      .map(response => this.getSuccessMessage(ListType.Cars)) //update succeeded  
      .catch(error => Observable.of("FAILURE: post to Cars did not succeed!")); 
  }

  public updateTwo(animalList: Animal[]): Observable<string> {
    return this._myApiSevice.postAnimalsNewOrder(animalList)
      .map(response => this.getSuccessMessage(ListType.Animals))
      .catch(error => Observable.of("FAILURE: post to Animals did not succeed!"));
  }

  public updateThree(bookList: Book[]): Observable<string> {
    return this._myApiSevice.postBooksNewOrder(bookList)
      .map(response => this.getSuccessMessage(ListType.Books)) //update succeeded
      .catch(error => Observable.of("FAILURE: post to Books did not succeed!"));
  }

  public getSuccessMessage(listType: ListType): string {
    return "SUCCESS: post to " + ListType[listType] + "succeed!";
  }
```

do you see something wrong?

this is the error in the console:

> EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Cannot resolve all parameters
>   for 'MyCmp'(undefined, ElementRef, MdDialog). Make sure that
>   all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type
>   annotations and that 'MyCmp' is decorated with Injectable.

**the enum is declerated in another class, this importing the class the the enums are coming from.**

and also if you have a suggestion for me how to gather also the failure message into a one function with the success message it will be lovely, thanks@!

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Comment: @MikeC just added the error to the question, sorry thought I did before.

Answer (score 0):

To get the value of a string from an enum type in typescript you need to do the following

```
enum ListType {
  Cars, 
  Animals, 
  Books
}
var booksStr = ListType[ListType.Books];
```

Here's a good explanation for why this is the case https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/enums.html

So your function would be something like

```
public getSuccessMessage(listType: ListType): string {
    return "SUCCESS: post to " + ListType[ListType.listType] + "succeed!";
}
```